# Show that an estimator is unbiased and it's variance goes towards 0? Poisson distribution

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let X be Poisson Distributed with expectation λt. Show that the estimator is unbiased and has a variance that goes towards 0 when the times goes to infinity.

λ^=X/t

I know that for these questions there is a good thing to have some kind of expectation, of how to progress with the question in relevance. However, I don't, I just don't understand at all. I have had 0 similar examples, and no tuition either.

E(X) is λt, and that's everything.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $E(X/t)=\lambda t/t=\lambda$, unbiased for $\lambda$. Now, for a Poisson r.v.  $E(X)=Var(X)$.  So $Var(X/t)=(1/t^2)Var(X)=(1/t^2)E(X)=\lambda/t$,  goes to 0  when $t$ goes to infinity.